# WinSxS filling so fast that DISM cleanup cannot operate

Tags: windows-10, dism, disk-cleanup, winsxs

I have a Windows 10 machine that is seeing the WinSxS folder fill up so quickly that DISM cannot run, and c: shows 0 bytes free. The machine also has a D: with 30 GB+ free space, so I have tried running

```
dism /online /cleanup-image /startcomponentcleanup /scratchdir:d:\dism_temp
```

If I run without the scratchdisk option, dism won't even start. If I run with the scratchdisk option, dism errors out at 20% with a 112 error "There is not enough space on the disk."

/resetbase switch also errors out on not enough disk space even with /scratchdir switch used.

Disk Cleanup buys me a few MB for a minute or two, which is enough to get dism started without the d: scratchdisk, but then the freed space magically disappears in a few minutes.

Is there some way around this?

Comment: Obvious question: how much free space is on C:? Have you tries to remove some non-essential files, or moving a folder, such as Documents to D:?

Comment: @cncmang Have a look at and run this PowerShell elevated: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28852786/automate-process-of-disk-cleanup-cleanmgr-exe-without-user-intervention/64106041#64106041 and then once it all completes, check to see if you got any space back. I would also admin elevate run `Start-Process -FilePath DISM.exe -ArgumentList '/online /Cleanup-Image /StartComponentCleanup'`

Comment: @DrMoishePippik : literally 0 bytes. When I remove non-essential files, something fills the space back up fairly quickly. This is an industrial computer, so there are very few non-essential files.

Comment: @VomitIT-ChunkyMessStyle I will give it a shot. Thanks!

Comment: @cncmang You might also check the size of the Event Viewer logs for the logs types. If the Event Viewer logs are not of importance to you, you could also try to purge those to get some additional quick space. Doing a `Ctrl+A` then delete all everything in `C:\Windows\Temp` and selecting the option to skip for all files if it pops up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For whatever reason, I was able to run DISM StartComponentCleanup by launching through Task Scheduler:

> Task Scheduler>Task Scheduler
> Library>Microsoft>Windows>Servicing>StartComponentCleanup

I also scheduled off-hours running of StartComponentCleanup to keep the WinSxS folder under control going forward.

EDIT:
Automatically scheduled tasks are auto-terminated if they take too long. I had to create the task, export it as an XML file, change the priority level to 4 (higher priority than 7, the default value) and import the updated task. At a higher priority, the task runs faster and doesn't time out, and is much more likely to complete.

Answer (score 1):

How big is WinSxS?  It is normally large, managed by Windows and should be left alone.

Look elsewhere to save space.  Check My Documents (and Pictures, Videos) for large or older files that can be moved elsewhere (your second drive) .

The Windows drive needs space for WinSxS (for repairs and management) and for updating (20GB + for feature updates).

Once you have moved some files, Admin Tools, Disk Cleanup works very well. Run Disk Cleanup, push "Cleanup System Files" and then (after it does its first run), select ALL items.

If you have done a feature update in past, Disk Cleanup will ask you about removing it and say OK or Yes.

Ultimately you may need a bigger drive C:.

Comment: It's on an industrial station, so unfortunately I don't have much leeway to change the drive size or even ask for downtime. Updates are deactivated, so I was surprised that it's still filling up.

Comment: I can't upvote you until I have a better rep, but I would if I could.

Comment: You can accept the answer with your rep level.

Answer (score 0):

Of many possible solutions that can be found in a google search, if all else fails, here's one more.

One-Note for WinSxS folder filling the hard drive:

Try this first:  Dism.exe /online /Cleanup-Image /StartComponentCleanup /ResetBase

Dism.exe can remove the WinSxS folder from powershell or Admin CMD in windows.

If you have already tried to use Dism.exe to clean the folder, here is an option if you can have physical hands on to the computer and feel like trying a Linux fix I found.

Danger Danger Danger
***  If you are worried about breaking the Windows system, STOP and get help or escalate.  Linux "assumes you know what you are doing" and will let you break stuff  ***

1. ```
      Obtain a USB that will boot a version of Linux.  In Cle Ops, I have (had) a USB for Linux \ that works well.  If you don't have one, create one by downloading linux and using Rufus to create the USB stick.
   ```

I like Mint for easy to use Linux https://linuxmint.com/
2)        Boot the computer with the USB in the computer and boot to the USB and start Linux.
3)        Once started, it will boot to the linux desktop.  Do not install Linux.  That will defeat the purpose of this.

4. ```
      Open up File Explorer, go to the drive that is normally the "C" drive (See picture above) and navigate to "Windows\WinSxS\Temp\InFlight" as shown.
   ```
5. ```
      There may be Hundreds of Thousands of folders here, so you will have to only do a chunk at a time, you will not be able to select all at once and delete.  Select a large chunk of files and then use "Shift" and "Delete" to delete these permanently and not fill up the trash can.  You will need to do this many times depending on how full this folder really is.
   ```

Start the delete, do something else, check again, start deleting more, get coffee, delete some more, etc.  I managed to go from 0Gb free to over 180Gb free.  Took a while, but saved re-imaging the drive.

Once the drive is cleaned to your satisfaction. Shut down linux, remove the bootable media, and boot back into Windows.

Comment: It is highly recommended one does NOT delete files and folders within `Windows\WinSxS\Temp\InFlight`.

Comment: Ah yes, the nuke-from-orbit option.